# PowerShell hangs when command saved to environment variable

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, batch-file

This Windows batch script works:

```
set MTCH=TOP = .
set REPL=TOP = %ProgramFiles%

powershell -Command "(Get-Content -raw Makefile.msc) -replace '%MTCH%', '%REPL%'" >> Makefile_.msc
```

This hangs PowerShell:

```
set MTCH=TOP = .
set REPL=TOP = %ProgramFiles%

set SCRIPT="(Get-Content -raw Makefile.msc) -replace '%MTCH%', '%REPL%'"
powershell -Command %SCRIPT% >> Makefile_.msc
```

Basically, I want to set the PowerShell command to a variable and then use this variable in the PowerShell command. How do I fix the second script?

Comment: It hangs CMD because you are using brackets.

Comment: confirm that the `%SCRIPT%` env var contains what you think it does. i suspect that is may have been munged by your insistence on mixing two different command interpreters. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Stop mixing batch commands with Powershell. Use their Powershell equivalent.

A variable in Powershell starts with `$`.

```
set MTCH=TOP = .
```

can be changed to:

```
 $MTCH = "TOP = ."
```

The whole code can be changed to something like the below:

```
$MTCH = "TOP = ."
$REPL= "TOP = %ProgramFiles%"

$SCRIPT="(Get-Content -raw Makefile.msc) -replace '%MTCH%', '%REPL%'"
powershell -Command $ | out-file Makefile_.msc
```

Comment: I know that I can have a pure PS script. I want to do what I asked though! My script runs from cmd.exe shell, period! But I need to use PowerShell commands from within the batch file.

Comment: @PChemGuy Does the file Makefile.msc exist as you are trying to get its content?

Comment: Yes. I repeat that the first version does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you can innclude your file over-write in your command variable, it should work:

```
set MTCH=TOP = .
set REPL=TOP = %ProgramFiles%

set SCRIPT="(Get-Content -raw Makefile.msc) -replace '%MTCH%', '%REPL%' | Set-Content Makefile_.msc -force"
powershell -Command %SCRIPT%
```

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this issue is due to this useless antimalware scan interface (amsi), so I ditched PowerShell completely.